# Print Unicode Character From Lua Interpreter

Tags: unicode, printing, lua, character

I'm losing my mind over this very simple problem. Let's consider the 2 following attempts to print the character `└` from the lua interpreter:

1)

```
Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(utf8.char(2514))
৒
```

2)

```
Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print("└")
└
```

First problem is that for some reason only option 2) actually works. But my real problem is that when I am running a script that does some printing using option 2) it actually prints the same gibberish as seen in option 1).
**This leads me to my main question, why?**

For info I'm simply running the script using the following command:

```
./lua53 path_to_my_script.lua
```

I feel like I am missing something very silly somewhere, yet I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

2514 is the *hexadecimal* code of that Unicode character (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2514/index.htm)).

Use

```
print(utf8.char(0x2514))
```

or

```
print("\u{2514}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer lhf. Interestingly both your answers work on Mac OS but don't work on Windows 10. On windows 10 I guess the following:

`Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`

`> print(utf8.char(0x2514))`

`Γöö`

`>  print("\u{2514}")`

`Γöö`

Comment: @MarkusL, isn't Windows UTF16? (I don't know anything about Windows, really.)

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. 0x2516 seems to be the UTF-16 code for `└` actually. Still quite confused haha. The fact that I have found so little about this issue makes me think I am overlooking something big.

Comment: I use Windows 10, and the default encoding for my console is [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). I also see `Γöö` for `'\u{2514}'`, so apparently you have the same default encoding. I can change the codepage to UTF-8 (codepage 65001) with `chcp 65001` (use `os.execute` to do this in Lua), but only if I have opened the Lua interpreter in cmd.exe. If I run lua.exe on its own, trying to switch to UTF-8 just makes non-ASCII characters (`'\128-\255'`) not display at all. I haven't found a way to fix this. Windows is annoying.

Comment: @MarkusL In Unicode's UTF-16 encoding, codepoints <U+10000 are encoded in one UTF-16 code unit and they have the same numeric value as the codepoint. Contrast with U+1F6B2 , which takes two code units: 0xD83D 0xDEB2. But, utf8.char has nothing to do with UTF-16. So, `print(utf8.char(0x1F6B2))` is okay; `print(utf8.char(0xD83D))` is not. It's not really relevant that 0x2516 is the single UTF-16 code unit for └.

Comment: What was happening is that `print(utf8.char(0x2514))` prints three bytes: `'\xE2\x94\x94'`. That byte sequence is the UTF-8 encoding of the codepoint U+2514. But the console interpreted the bytes according to its default encoding, codepage 437, where `'\xE2'` represents U+0393 (Greek capital letter gamma) and `'\x94'` represents U+00F6 (Latin small letter o with diaeresis), so it printed those characters. See [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: @cyclaminist, on windows 10 I ran lua53.exe from both cmd and PowerShell. Then I typed the command `os.execute("chcp 65001")` followed by `print("\u{2514}")` and it prints a blank line in both cases.

Comment: @MarkusL.: Huh, right now the same is happening for me. It used to work. There might be something else that I did to get UTF-8 to work, and that has now been undone by a Windows update.